# I can not understand the work WakefulBroadcastReceiver (in GCM)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I connected in the project GCM which uses WakefulBroadcastReceiver. I have everything working but there was a misunderstanding. I write in the manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name=".service.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.skip.client.customer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

ie I created `intent-filter` who received `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />` start my `GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver`

the question is. if I write another application with the exact same `intent-filter` it will also be able to receive notifications from GCM? If not (and I think that there is) then how is recognition? If both applications are configured on the same `intent-filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Other application will have other packageName:

```
 <category android:name="com.skip.client.customer" />
```

So, do not worry about receiving your pushes from other applications

Comment: I understand that. I do not understand how it works. ie in what place is linking to my package name? Google is aware of the name of my package? otherwise it generates intent that sends me?